# How to serialize a class in IOS sdk (Objective-c)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, serialization, sbjson

How to serialize the following class in objective-c so that it can be used with SBJson?

I get "JSON serialisation not supported for Animal" error when I use this code.

Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

The contents of Animal.h file is as below

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Animal : NSObject<NSCoding> {
    NSString *name;
    NSString *description;
    NSString *imageURL;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *imageURL;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)n description:(NSString *)d url:(NSString *)u;

@end
```

The contents of Animal.m file is as below

```
#import "Animal.h"

@implementation Animal
@synthesize name, description, imageURL;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)n description:(NSString *)d url:(NSString *)u {
    self.name = n;
    self.description = d;
    self.imageURL = u;
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        name = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"] retain];
        description = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"description"] retain];
        imageURL = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"imageURL"] retain];
    }
    return [self initWithName:name description:description url:imageURL];
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [super encodeWithCoder:encoder];
    [encoder encodeObject:name forKey:@"name"];
    [encoder encodeObject:description forKey:@"description"];
    [encoder encodeObject:imageURL forKey:@"imageURL"];
}    

@end
```

Answer (score 9):

Make your custom class conform to `NSCoding` protocol and then serialize it.

For more info, visit the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Archiving/Articles/serializing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000952-BABBEJEE)

Also, this [link](http://jonathanhui.com/ios-data-serialization-archive) will also help you.
As suggested in this link, archive your custom class to NSData and serialize that as provided in the Apple documentation.

**Edit**
Make your `Animal.m` as follows:

```
#import "Animal.h"

@implementation Animal
@synthesize name, description, imageURL;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)n description:(NSString *)d url:(NSString *)u {
    self = [super init];
    if( self )
    {
       self.name = n;
       self.description = d;
       self.imageURL = u;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if( self )
    {
        self.name = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
        self.description = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"description"];
        self.imageURL = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"imageURL"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeObject:name forKey:@"name"];
    [encoder encodeObject:description forKey:@"description"];
    [encoder encodeObject:imageURL forKey:@"imageURL"];
}    

@end
```

Comment: The second link is the key. You use `[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:(id)]` and `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:(NSData *)]` to serialize and unserialize objects.

Answer (score 4):

To actually answer your question on how to do it **using SBJson**: Implement the `proxyForJson` method. Unless you are serializing an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` you must override this method for serialization to work.

You can see that this is the case by looking at the SBJson source code (in SBJsonWriter.m):

```
- (NSData*)dataWithObject:(id)object {    
...   
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
                ok = [streamWriter writeObject:object];

            else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
                ok = [streamWriter writeArray:object];

            else if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(proxyForJson)])
                return [self dataWithObject:[object proxyForJson]];
            else {
                self.error = @"Not valid type for JSON";
                return nil;
            }
    ...
    }
}
```

Implement `proxyForJson` in `Animal.m` like this (not tested):

```
- (NSDictionary*) proxyForJson
{
return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.name, @"name",
                                                  self.description, @"description",
                                                  self.imageURL, @"imageURL", 
                                                  nil];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the newly introduced NSJSONSerialization class:

[NSJSONSerialization class](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 3):

This open source project [JSONCoding](https://github.com/ontometrics/JSONCoding) makes the whole process pretty simple, using the new sdk class in conjunction with the NSCoding protocol.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can check out this if it helps you: [Make a Custom Class Serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182115/make-a-custom-class-serializable-in-objective-c-iphone)

Comment: I have added the following methods as said in this link, but still I am getting the error message as "JSON serialisation not supported for Animal" 
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder; 
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder;

Comment: i think nscoding is a protocol and we should implement in <nscoding> this way but still if you are not getting my point then chekc out this one http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager   here is the purpose is different of the tutorial but the use of  nscoding you can learn from here i think ..

Comment: I have updated the original question with the source code along with the changes suggested in the links that you have shared.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [Property List Programming Guide - Serializing a Property List](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/SerializePlist/SerializePlist.html)

and the similar post here:
[Make a Custom Class Serializable in Objective-c/iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182115/make-a-custom-class-serializable-in-objective-c-iphone)

[Object serialization in XML format using Obj-C / iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292355/object-serialization-in-xml-format-using-obj-c-iphone-sdk)

Comment: I have added the following methods as said in the post "Make a Custom Class Serializable in Objective-c/iPhone?", but still I am getting the error message as "JSON serialisation not supported for Animal"

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder;

Comment: Did you make the class conform to `NSCoding` protocol?

Comment: I am new to writing code for IPhone app. Can you look at the source code in my orginal question and point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

See also https://github.com/jsonmodel/jsonmodel

> Magical Data Modeling Framework for JSON - allows rapid creation of
>   smart data models. You can use it in your iOS, macOS, watchOS and tvOS
>   apps.

This is also the chosen library for the Objective-c Swagger client.